# Extract rewards address for validators

Tags: addresses, eth-2.0, validators

Is there a way to link the `withdrawal_credentials` from a deposit into the eth2 deposit contract with the address which will receive the validating rewards?

For example, I know that **Lido** uses the following `withdrawal_credentials: 010000000000000000000000B9D7934878B5FB9610B3FE8A5E441E8FAD7E293F` and that the rewards are received in the following address `0x388c818ca8b9251b393131c08a736a67ccb19297`. Is there a way to extract the address from the withdrawal credentials ?

Answer (score 4):

You might be confusing things between execution layer rewards and consensus layer rewards. The withdrawal credential used by Lido is pointing all the withdrawals to `0xB9D7934878B5FB9610B3FE8A5E441E8FAD7E293F`. Now that the merge has occured, validators have to propose the blocks on the execution layer. Just like miners, validators are receiving the rewards from the transaction tips or mev bribes. These execution layer rewards are actually never leaving the execution layer and are available right away. In the case of Lido, operators are asked to send the rewards to `0x388c818ca8b9251b393131c08a736a67ccb19297`.

To answer the initial question:

- withdrawal credentials starting with `01` are using regular addresses for the withdrawal destination (so the last 20 bytes represent the address)
- the ones starting with `00` are handled by BLS keys that will probably need to perform an extra operation on the execution layer to specify where the rewards can go on the execution layers.